# Rust `format!()` print `variable=value` like python's `f"{variable=}"

Tags: rust, format

In python, I can include an `=` after a formatting parameter to print the value of the variable as well as the variable name:

```py
var = 10
f"{var=}" # -> "var=10"
```

Is there a way to do this in Rust with the `format!()` macro? I know about the dbg! macro, but this string is going to a progress bar and dbg! doesn't return a string.

I'd like something like `format!("{var:=}")` or maybe `format!("{var=}")` but neither of those work.

To clarify, I'd like to *not* have to type the variable name, but still have it printed out. For example, if I'm printing out a long line of variables like:

```rs
println!("variable1={variable1}, variable2={variable2}, variable3={variable3}, variable4={variable4}");
```

Explicitly writing out the variable names gets old very quickly, and if I rename the variable then rust-analyzer doesn't pick up the string and will leave me with a situation like `"old_name={new_name}"`.

It's a small thing, but I find `f"{var1=}"` super useful in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's anything like that in `std` or in the `format!` macro itself. If you just need the output similar to what `dbg!` does but as a `String`, you can write a simple macro for that:

```rust
macro_rules! my_format {
    ($val:expr $(,)?) => {
        format!("{} = {:#?}", stringify!($val), $val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let value = 42;
    let s = my_format!(value);
    println!("{s}"); // prints out "value = 42"
}
```

You could even do it without a macro, with just a function. If you want to use it as a part of some longer string, you would have to resort to `format!("My value: {}", my_format!(value));` though.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f5b225321d90c6c5894a0927712489e0)

Comment: Okay thanks! that looks promising, although I haven't written a macro before so would have to explore that a bit. I'll see if any other answers come up and then accept your solution.

Comment: Note that generally, the output of `stringify!()` isn't guaranteed (whitespaces and so) so it is good for debug output (e.g. `dbg!()`), but less for actual user-facing output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with fstring: see https://docs.rs/fstrings/latest/fstrings/ :

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate fstrings;

...

        // You can use fstrings to debug by appending a `=` after the
        // interpolated expression.
        let x = 0b_101010;
        assert_eq!(
            f!("In this context {x=}"),
            "In this context x = 42",
        );
```

Comment: Nice crate! Although, the crate declares itself as obsolete now, so I'd be wary of using it.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know this exists, although it's a pity this didn't make it into RFC2795 (which is the one that made `println!("{x}");` valid), as pulling in an self-described obsolete crate for this use-case might be a bit too much.